# Execution Timeout Expired - Randomly for simple update command

Tags: sql, asp.net, entity-framework-6, timeout

I am randomly getting execution timeout expired error using the Entity Framework (EF6). At the time of executing the below update command it gives randomly execution timeout error.

> UPDATE [dbo].[EmployeeTable] SET [Name]=@0,[JoiningDate]=@1 WHERE
>   ([EmpId]=@2)

The above update command is simple and it takes 2-5 seconds to update the EmployeeTable. But sometime the same update query takes 40-50 seconds and leads the error as

> Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to
>   completion of the operation or the server is not responding. the
>   statement has been terminated

.

For that I updated my code inside constructor of **MyApplicationContext** class can be changed to include the following property

> this.Database.CommandTimeout = 180;

The above command should resolve my timeout issue. But I can’t find out the root cause of that issue.

For my understanding this type of timeout issue can have three causes;

1. There's a deadlock somewhere
2. The database's statistics and/or query plan cache are incorrect
3. The query is too complex and needs to be tuned

Can you please tell me what the main root cause of that error is?

Comment: Did you get any solution to this..? I am also facing a similar issue.

Comment: No, I think the issue in Entity Framework dll.

Comment: I got a workaround by removing .net Transactions.. and it worked perfectly..

Comment: @Abi, Can you please explain more details.

Comment: I was using transactions in .Net for SQL update operation along with EF.. and got the Timeout exception.. when i removed transactions it was resolved.. Hope its clear now.

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[EmployeeTable]
    SET [Name] = @0,
        [JoiningDate] = @1
    WHERE ([EmpId]=@2);
```

Should not normally take 2 seconds.  It is (presumably) updating a single row and that is not a 2-second operation, even on a pretty large table.  Do you have an index on `EmployeeTable(EmpId)`?  If not, that would explain the 2 seconds as well as the potential for deadlock.

If you do have an index, this perhaps something else is going on.  One place to look is for any triggers on the table.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon, I have an Index on EmployeeTable. But I don't have any triggers on that table. One thing is this issue happens only on Production database not on DEV or QA databases.

Answer (score 0):

If it's random, maybe something else is accessing the database while your application is updating rows.

We got the same exact issue. In our case, the root cause was BO reports being run on the production database. These reports were locking rows and causing timeouts in our applications (randomly since these reports were executed on demand).

Other things that you might want to check:

- Do you have complex triggers on your table ?
- Does all foreign keys used in your table are indexed in the foreign tables ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same sort of problem.
My table (300k rows) could not contain primary keys and had no relationships.

- Updates freezed randomly when I updated a single row (identified by ID (not unique) and another field).
- Delete always timed-out.

The solution : change one column and set is as an index (ID in my case).

PS : Index is not the same as a primary key.